# How do you move an array into another and leave the first one empty?

Tags: ruby, arrays, merge

I'm looking for a way to move one array into another and emptying it. In this example:

```
a1 = [1,2]
a2 = [3,4]
```

I want to add a2 to a1 and then a2 to be empty. I want the result to look like:

```
a1 # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
a2 # => []
```

The arrays can vary in size, so I need something that is not specific to one element like push/pop/shift/unshift. Or maybe I'm not using these properly. I did the following, but was wondering if there is a better way:

```
a1.concat(a2)
a2.clear
a1 # => [1, 2, 3, 4]
a2 # => [3, 4]
```

Comment: Oops, I wrote an answer (now deleted) before realising that it's exactly what you tried already. I honestly think that's the simplest way—using `#clear` in the second line.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments and solutions.  I'm very new to this site.  I don't want to get penalized for asking this... but I don't understand why my question was down voted to a "-1."  Thank you again for all of your help!

Comment: Who knows why someone down-voted it. Seems like a reasonable question to me. I've up-voted to compensate. :-)

Comment: BTW, what I wrote in my deleted answer was 'If `a2.clear` returned the emptied elements, it would be a simple one liner. But it doesn't, so I'd do it in two.' I think what you did is cleaner than the solution using `slice!`, even though it takes an extra line.

Comment: Kal - Thanks for the comment and for the up-vote!  I read all the rules before posting and tried to be extra careful in my question.  I just wanted to make sure I didn't break a rule inadvertently.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

```
a1.concat(a2.slice!(0..-1))
```

Will give you what you want in one line. The `slice!` method will take everything from the one array and concat adds it to the other.

```
a1 = [1,2]
a2 = [3,4]
a1.concat(a2.slice!(0..-1)) # => [1, 2, 3, 4] 
a2 # => []
```

Comment: Also works fine without all the parentheses in Ruby 2.1.0: `a1.concat a2.slice! 0..-1`. Your answer is quite concise, and I like it for that reason; however, bang methods can sometimes return nil and break longer method chains, so I'd personally recommend a more explicit set of assignments. YMMV.

Comment: Thank you. In certain situations I prefer the parentheses just to make it more explicit what is going on to someone else. That's interesting about the nil return, I hadn't thought of that. Can you give an example?

Comment: Anytime the index is out of range, *slice!* will return *nil*. The following chain will raise NoMethodError when Array#first is called: `a1 = [1,2]; a2 = [3,4]; a2.slice!(50).first`.

Comment: In this example slice! is safe to use because 0..-1 is never out of range, even if the array is empty.

Answer (score 1):

### Use Concatenation

Use the [Array#+](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Array.html#method-i-2B) to concatenate the arrays and assign the result to *a1*, then set *a2* equal to an empty array. For example:

```
a1  = [1,2]
a2  = [3,4]
a1 += a2
a2  = []

a1
# => [1, 2, 3, 4]
a2
# => []
```

Comment: This is how I would do it too.  It's the same as what Caroleen suggested, just a different way of expressing it.  I don't understand the point of slicing or shifting to combine two ultra-simple statements into one one that takes 5.0 rather than 0.5 seconds to comprehend.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Array#concat appends to *self*, while Array#+ returns a new array. This won't matter to the OP, but it's a distinction worth noting for future visitors. However, I agree with you: clarity trumps conciseness, except when playing code golf. :)

Answer (score 0):

You might look at the shift or slice! methods. Both will return a chunk of an array after removing it.

If you know the number of values you want to shift off the front of the array, this works:

```
a1.concat(a2.shift(2))
```

Alternatively, if you want to slice out the entire array, this works:

```
a1.concat(a2.slice!(0..-1))
```

The range of 0..-1 refers to the first element through the last element.

Comment: And you could replace `shift(2)` with `shift(a2.size)`, of course, which you could also write `a1 += a2.shift(a2.size)`.

Comment: Your `slice` will not remove the elements from the `a2` array. You need the bang method `slice!`.

Comment: @beartech Right you are. Shift implies a change. Shift doesn't without the !. Updating the answer.